# Getting error - class cv::Mat’ has no member named ‘get’ when using Mat.get....is it deprecated?

Tags: c++, opencv

I would just like a quick simple function that I can give a row and col number for  a mat object and have it output the value of the element at that location...I googled and found a few sites recommending 'Mat.get(int row, int col)' but I'm getting error when I try to use it

Here is my code the error is in the post title

```
Mat M(2,2, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0,0,255));


cout << "b = " << endl << " " << M.get(0, 0) << endl << endl;
```

I don't want to have to write a long for loop to retrieve on pixel...can some one help me figure out why I'm getting this error or recommend a quick 1 liner to get just the value of a single element in a mat object...But the one liner needs to be able to be run without the type being known so Mat.at won't work....Googling a lot brought up no easy 1 liners....any help is appreciated

Edit:

Using M.at as you suggested as this

```
cout << "M.at = " << endl << " " <<a.at<uchar>(0, 0) << endl << endl;
```

The ouput is this

```
M.at = 
^@
```

the kind of weird symbol you get when you don't do it right...I was trying to avoid M.at because I thought it needed a type which I don't want to have to enter....Any help is appreciated

Edit 2: thanks for getting back to me so soon...I found one error my mat was a CV_64F I changed it for another reason...I changed it back to CV_8UC3  and also tried CV_8UC1 and got the following output for both

```
M =
d(yes letter d)
```

Any advice from here is appreciated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `get()` method for `cv::Mat`, you should use [`Mat::at()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at) instead:

```
M.at<uchar>(0, 0)
```

---

**Edit:** If your Mat is of type 'CV_64F', you should use

```
M.at<double>(0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply...would you mind seeing latest Edit

Comment: @EdwardMonney If your mat is defined with type `CV_8U`, it should work for `at<uchar>`.

Comment: @ herohuyongtao  Okay I got it working ...It was the scalar ... Mat::at wasn't returning all the scalar elements...just the first...Thanks for your help on this=)

Comment: I am not able to find even at method in java implementation of openCv, Can you please have one look at my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62443053/reading-values-in-opencv-face-lbphfacerecognizer-gethistograms